# How do I fix a counting program where the current number is incremented when a duplicate author is detected?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm having a bit of trouble: I made a counting channel and this part of my code:

```
                recent_author = (await message.channel.history(limit=2).flatten())[1].author
                if message.author == recent_author:
                    await message.author.send(f"You can't hog this channel, let someone else have a turn!")
                    await message.delete()
```

prevents users from sending messages more than once; but, when the message is deleted, the variable that holds the current number is incremented. That's not supposed to happen but it does: I've tried doing  so many things at this point like moving this piece of code below other pieces of code in the event function or merging the code into an if else statement--nothing seems to solve my problem. I was thinking about subtracting 1 from the current number when a duplicate author is detected; however, that would mean subtracting 1 for anything other than a number.

Here's my full code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import re


class Counting(commands.Cog):
    """ Users take turns incrementing a number. """

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.count_channel = 736241527847911494
        self.cum_num = 98
        self.num_regex = re.compile(r'(^\d+)')

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.channel.id == self.count_channel:
            try:
                recent_author = (await message.channel.history(limit=2).flatten())[1].author
                if message.author == recent_author:
                    await message.author.send(f"You can't hog this channel, let someone else have a turn!")
                    await message.delete()

                match_obj = self.num_regex.search(message.content)
                if int(match_obj.group(1)) != self.cum_num + 1:
                    await message.author.send(f'Your message must start with **{self.cum_num + 1}**!')
                    await message.delete()
                else:
                    self.cum_num += 1
            except AttributeError:
                await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the if/else logic needs tweaking.

Directly after your check for the duplicate author it initialises and sets `match_obj` then runs the if statement.

So despite the message being removed from the text channel if the message content was valid then it will still increment the counter because nothing is preventing it from running that logic.

It looks to me like you will want to structure it as follows:

```
recent_author = (await message.channel.history(limit=2).flatten())[1].author
if message.author == recent_author:
    await message.author.send(f"You can't hog this channel, let someone else have a turn!")
    await message.delete()
else:
    match_obj = self.num_regex.search(message.content)
    if int(match_obj.group(1)) != self.cum_num + 1:
        await message.author.send(f'Your message must start with **{self.cum_num + 1}**!')
        await message.delete()
    else:
        self.cum_num += 1
```

This way if the latest author is the duplicate author it won't call the code in the else block. However, if it is not a duplicate author it will run the next stage of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_fo#discord.Client.wait_for) and in the check compare user names to the previous message, if they are the same then you can do something if not you can ignore it. You could also try using a database or memory for this.